# While loop won't end after second input "No"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my code to end after "thank you for playing", however underneath it, i get the message going back to "Guess my number:". I appreciate the help and advice! Thank you

```py
def guess_number():
    import random
    import sys
    guessesTaken = 0
    max_number = float(input("What should the maxium number be for this game be? "))
    print("")
    number = random.randint(1,max_number)
    
    
     while (guessesTaken) < 100000:
        guesses = float(input("Guess my number: "))
        guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

        if guesses < number:
            print("Your guess is too low.")
            print("")

        elif guesses > number:
            print("Your guess is too high.")
            print("")
    
        elif guesses == number: 
            print("You guessed my number!")
            print("")
            again = (input("Do you wish to play again? (Y/N): "))
            print("")
            if again.lower() == "y":   
                guess_number()
            else:
                print("")
                print("Thank you for playing!")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html you just need to include a `break`. This will end the while loop.

Comment: Thank you! I just had my break statement in the wrong place

Answer (score 2):

Instead of print("thank you for playing") try return "Thank you for playing!"

Comment: I figured it out, I had my break statement in the wrong place. It works now! Thank you